# jQuery mobile hiding initial page instead of removing it

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've been searching for a way to remove the initial page container after jQuery mobile loaded the next page content via **$.mobile.changePage(...)**

What I'm experiencing is that this initial DIV element, created when the page is first shown will always remain on the page - and will only be **hidden** after calling $.mobile.changePage(...)

I need this initial page container to be removed instead, since some old data reside there that should be reset on first page change.

Anyone has a solution? Been searching the web for it but to no avail.

I have also tried to do $('#first-page').remove() after I called $.mobile.changePage(...), but that will remove the initial page and make the new loaded page hidden!

**EDIT:** solved by clearing up the initial DIV using *.html("")*

Comment: why do you need the initial page to be removed? Could you just update the values of the data?

Comment: I'd rather not have unnecessary DOM elements on the page, causing memory growth on mobile devices... but you gave me an idea - maybe I can clear up the inital page element instead of trying to hide it... will try that asap, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make next page load without ajax, this should remove the initial page.

`data-ajax="false"`

Hope this helps!

Comment: sorry, can't do that... I need to retain the AJAX functionality

Comment: I solved this by actually clearing the initial page div completely using .html(""). Still - your answer is valid for this case if I didn't need to preserverve AJAX calls, so accept that is :)

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you are dynamically creating these pages.  There is a hidden method in the API, but you can apply it to any page and then upon that page's exit, it will be removed.

```
$.mobile._bindPageRemove
```

So, it might look like this

```
newpage.attr( "data-" + $.mobile.ns + "external-page", true ).one( 'pagecreate', $.mobile._bindPageRemove );
```

NOTE:  Since this is a hidden method, it is part of the hidden API and could be subject to change without notice upon upgrade.  Test carefully upon upgrade if you use this.

Comment: upvoted for your insight, although I don't really want to use undocumented functionality... but thanks anwyay :)

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
 $.mobile.changePage('login.html', {changeHash:false});
```

> changeHash (default: true) Type: Boolean Decides if the hash in the
>   location bar should be updated. This has the effect of creating a new
>   browser history entry. It also means that, if set to false, the
>   incoming page will replace the current page in the browser history, so
>   the page from which the user is navigating away will not be reachable
>   via the browser's "Back" button.